# How to place a new generated div aside to another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I got a div where I place a Java Script generated chart. Also, I got another div where I print out a table with chart data results.

One example is:

[image]

However, for UX purposes I prefer the table to be placed on the right side of the chart. Or what's more, making it appear on the right side. (I already use jQuery to do a `$("#resultados").remove()` and `$("body").append("<table...</table>)`.

How can I make the chart div, which markup is `<div id="placeholder" style="width:1200px;height:700px"></div>` resize down and make place to another generated div to its right side?

So far, thinking about already marked up divs I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/diegoaguilar/P3GpM/) but I'm not getting the results I want as:

1. The table div appears first and I want the opposite.
2. They don't take together the whole outer div width.

Comment: do u have jsfiddeel ?

Comment: if you are placing div from one div to another then avoid inline css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrap your table with a right floating div by settting `float:"right"` in its style.
2. Make placeholder div to float on left (`float:left`).
3. To dynamically change its size, use : `$("#placeholder").css({"width":"600px");`
4. Finally , add a clear div (`clear:both`);

Comment: Thanks! What's the intention of the clear div? As a container? How would your answer change my fiddle?

Comment: You sent original fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of inline css chart.

**CSS**

```
.first{
  width:1200px;
  height:700px;
}

.second{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
```

**Code**

```
$("#placeholder").appendTo("#anotherPlaceholder").toggleClass("first second");
```

Comment: Thanks, I get close to what I want with it. Check my edit and the fiddle I linked. Let's say chart is contained in `placeholder` div and table in `table`, how would css and code look like?

Comment: So the function of the jQuery statement is to change the style of any div? I don't understand the `.appendTo("#anotherPlaceholder").` part

Comment: [.appendTo()](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) used to move any element from one place to another place and toggleClass() use to change the class from 'first' to 'second'.

Comment: So you suggest like:

`$("#table").appendTo("#chart")`?