# Why adding line border to a css messes up its correct displacement?

Tags: css, html

Based on [answer](http://jsfiddle.net/P3GpM/5/) from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163429/how-to-place-a-new-generated-div-aside-to-another-div) I tried to add a line border to a div placed inside an outer one.

However this causes the div to [mess up](http://jsfiddle.net/diegoaguilar/7g4LJ/) Why?

**Mark up**

```
<div id="outer">
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <div id="table"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer{

width: 1300px; 
height: 640px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#chart{

  float:left;
  width: 900px;
  height: 100%;
  left:0;
  background-color: red;
}

#table{

  float:right;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  right:400;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid back;

}
```

Comment: Use `box-sizing:border-box` http://jsfiddle.net/PMZ3r/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

400px + 2 border edges = 402px. 402px + 900px = 1302px which is too wide for your 1300px container so the float drops down.

Simplest fix is to replace the border with an outline:

`outline : 1px solid black;`

Answer (score 4):

That's because of the box model... box model considers the dimensions of the content are the ones defined by height and width in the CSS..

Now you put height: 100% that's for the content.. any borders added will be added to that..

The solution is to override the box model calculations for the element by:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

This way height and width will include paddings and borders

Answer (score 2):

Use this property in you css:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox */
```

With this you can define certain elements to fit an area in a certain way.

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 1):

`border` and `padding` both add to the `width` and `height` of element. Decrease the `height` and `width` to keep the same total dimensions.